# How to create Line-less Fraction followed by other value

Tags: equations

May I know how to achieve something similar in the attached picture.

Thanks in advance for any hint[image]

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far? Because this is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior in display math. If you also want it in inline math, you can use `\limits`, but that will mess up your line spacing, so I would not recommend it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Display math:
\[
    \max_{1 \leq k \leq m} S_k = S_{k_0}
\]

Inline math: \(\max_{1 \leq k \leq m} S_k = S_{k_0}\)

Inline math with \verb|\limits|: \(\max\limits_{1 \leq k \leq m} S_k = S_{k_0}\)
Note, however, that this does not look very nice inside a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I accepted this as answer due to extra explaination given

Answer (score 2):

`\lim` is math operator, which indices (as all operators) in display math environment put below it, in inline equation wrote as subscript.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\max_{l\leq k\leq m} s_k = s_{k_0}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I really safe my day. Apparently, I cannot increase the rate for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Just another possibility (it gives the same result) to the previous answers that are already very very good, you could also use a more robust command `\substack` that can also include additional lines under the command `\max`.
I have added also `\usepackage{mathpazo}` to have the same your screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\[
\max_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq m}}  S_k = S_{k_0}
\]
\end{document}
```